# Socket IO Socket won't connect on Motorola device

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io

I am building an app that uses Socket IO to communicate with a server. I have been testing on an Xperia Z2 running Android 6.0.1. When I tested it today on a Motorola Moto x running 6.0 and the socket won't connect while still working fine on the Sony device. I have searched around and the only suggestion that keeps popping up is to ensure that the Internet permission is declared in the manifest, which it is.
The network is not connected to the internet but the server is running on the network so I don't think that should make a difference.

The Socket is being created using an IP-address and port number that it gets from a service found using Androids Network discovery.

The network configuration is one of two. The only one I can test at the moment  is a micro controller device acting as an access point that is running a service and listens for socket IO requests.

What reasons might exist for a socket being able to connect on one device and not on another.

Comment: I can imagine many possible problems, like not matching (fixed) ip addresses, ip address conflicts, firewall etc. Maybe you could give us some more information about your network configuration / topology? And maybe also some relevant part of your code?

Comment: @RolandBär I Have added more information re the network. not sure what code to post. and the key point for me is that it runs fine every time on the sony device but not at all on the moto.

Comment: Can you connect with another tool to your server from the motorola (like telnet client, browser ...) 'by hand'? Or maybe you can add another computer to the network to check the data sent over the network with wireshark or a similar tool?

Comment: Monitoring the traffic wont do much good as the socket wont connect and thus not send any data. I will try the other suggestion and come back to you, but unfortunately I have to park this for today as i have to leave

Comment: With Wireshark you can not only see the data that travels through your net but also the connection attempts including sender and receiver ip address and port. BTW: Do you get any error messages / exceptions on the motorola?